# What does cleave mean with regards to a pan of batter?

Tags: cake

When pouring a Japanese Cheesecake into the baking pan recipe states do not "cleave"...
I have never seen this term Ina recipe.. Please advise!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The English definition of "cleave" is to split or sever something (at least according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cleave&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleave) has a slightly different take on it).

So, in a cheesecake recipe, it makes sense to me that it is asking that you pour the batter continuously, not in parts. I doubt such a thing would make a huge difference, but consider that it is a Japanese recipe. If such a thing could be expected in a recipe, I would expect to see it in a Japanese recipe.

Comment: Sometimes cake batter is kind of "cleaved" by pressing an oiled knife into it to encourage a neat split, but it's usually things like poundcakes. I wonder if this is a translation issue?